# Launch my app from link in email, but link was filtered by gmail ,  How can I do ?  ask for Help !

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser

I want to launch my app from link in email.  this the link is base on special schema.

I use the  in my app's activity (AndroidManifest.xml) :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="ace" android:host="samuel"/>
</intent-filter>*
```

In my app, when user click the 'Share by Email' button, It will open gmail app to send email.

```
Intent mailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
mailIntent.setType("plain/test");
mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{});
mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{});
mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{});
mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(emailBody));

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "You need to configure gmail..."));*
```

---

'emailBody' contain the special URL link:  [ace:adid=9ca98efe-ef48-47c0-aff5-058224b3093d](http://ace://samuel?adid=9ca98efe-ef48-47c0-aff5-058224b3093d)

---

When I send this email to others, The recipient open the mail, there is no such a special URL link.

I do not know why ? When I use other email (not gmail) send the same html content, It's ok.
the recipient can see the special URL link.

Comment: ace://samuel?adid=9ca98efe-ef48-47c0-aff5-058224b3093d

Comment: 'emailBody' = <div><a href ='ace://samuel?adid=9ca98efe-ef48-47c0-aff5-058224b3093d'> ace:adid=9ca98efe-ef48-47c0-aff5-058224b3093d</a></div>

Answer (score 2):

There might be some filtering out. I was able to bipass a similar restriction by using tinyurl. You could use a small php script to convert a get request to an ace:// link.

Comment: hi, Oldarney, thanks for your answer, But, I don't understand what you mean. Can you give me some more detail solutions ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

@Samuel.Cai I believe that @Oldarney was telling you to put your URL into TinyURL.com (I did it for you) and put this in your email body: http://tinyurl.com/a7y2mzn

It worked for me, although you have to be online for your browser to do that redirect unfortunately. Your safest bet is probably to do

'emailBody' =  ace://samuel?adid=9ca98efe-ef48-47c0-aff5-058224b3093d

and telling the users to copy-paste into the browser if the link doesn't work!

Hope that's helpful.